# PHP Remote MySQL problems

Tags: php, mysql

Like 2-3 months ago i set up a cronjob to run a php-script ever minute. This PHP-script simply queried a remote MySQL database of mine, and emailed me if any updates.

This worked fine up until about a week ago. I stopped receiving the email and found that the PHP-script wasn't able to connect anymore.

I am able to run the exact same script from other servers.

> Warning: mysql_connect()
>   [function.mysql-connect]: Can't
>   connect to MySQL server on '***removed***'
>   (4) in
>   /home/somefolder/public_html/somefolder/cronjob.php
>   on line 4

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you enter that 'removed' there for secrecy/security reasons? Or does it actually say that?

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` contain something helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

You're server might have blocked the outgoing connection because it was using bandwidth every minute(not much, I know..). You should contact your server manager, to check if this is true.

Comment: Could be this, but seems unlikely that they would notice a tiny php-script that runs every minute and that requires minimal resources.

Comment: One query per minute is not a 'bandwidth' for MySQL server.

Comment: But it could be that the server thinks this is a miscellaneous script that sends spam.

Comment: I guess. Seems weird tho. It only sent 1 to 10 emails a day. And to my own email account only.

Comment: But wouldnt they then block me from sending mails, instead of blocking remote mysql connection?